# What's the meaning of this phrase "of ready" and usage of this "of "?

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning

I came across this sentence

> He was brisk and **of ready**, lively wit, so that nobody or nothing could
>   worst him.

This is from English Fairy Tales. What's the meaning of this phrase "of ready" and usage of this "of "?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> He was brisk and of ready, lively wit, so that nobody or nothing could worst him.

It means *he was witty* (Showing or characterized by quick and inventive verbal humour). *Wit* is a noun, so to characterize his wit we use adjectives (ready and lively). Since you can't add these adjectives to *witty*, you should use a noun phrase meaning *of such quality* (possessing this quality):

> of ready, lively wit.

Answer (score 1):

"to be of" means "to posess intrinsically". See http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/be-of

(That link doesn't seem to contain any examples of the other meaning given, "to give rise to", and I can't think of any either!)

In simpler modern English, the sentence could be written "He was active and energetic, and had a ready, lively wit..."